# How to use EnumAccess in Serde?

Tags: serialization, enums, rust, serde

I am deserializing a externally coded enum for Avro. I have created an enum which matches it schema and I don't know how to take the variant identifer (a number) and choose the proper enum variant.

The target struct:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct UT {
    timestamp: Timestamp,
    metric: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
enum Timestamp {
    Long(u64),
    Int(i64),
    Float(f32),
    Double(f64)
}
```

When I get to `deserialize_enum`, I can read the variant id out of the stream but I don't know how to use it to choose the variant.

Dispatching to an enum variant is done by `AvroEnumVisitor` which implements both `EnumAccess` and `VariantAccess`. I can't get my code in `VariantAccess` to be called. `EnumAccess`s `variant_seed` is invoked by I don't know how to direct it, here's the nitty gritty:

```
// `EnumAccess` is provided to the `Visitor` to give it the ability to determine
// which variant of the enum is supposed to be deserialized.
//
// Note that all enum deserialization methods in Serde refer exclusively to the
// "externally tagged" enum representation.
impl<'de, 'a> EnumAccess<'de> for AvroEnumVisitor<'a, 'de> {
    type Error = AvroError;
    type Variant = Self;

    fn variant_seed<V>(self, seed: V) -> Result<(V::Value, Self::Variant), Self::Error>
        where
            V: serde::de::DeserializeSeed<'de>,
    {
        println!("EnumAccess::variant_seed");

        // !!! This is the index in to the timestamp enum
        let variant = self.de.visit_varint();
        // !!! it's 1, corresponding to Int(i64)

        // This is code I just copy/pasted
        let val = match seed.deserialize(&mut *self.de) {
            Ok(t) => t,
            Err(e) => {
                println!("error! {:#?}", e);
                panic!("not sure how to direct deserialize");
            }
        };

        Ok((val,self))
    }
}
```

([playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7cbe56f7fd8b81e34ee79020d8e6d75d&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015))

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. Emphasis on **minimal**. It *appears* that your question boils down to "how do I convert an integer to an enum in Serde", but there's simply **so much** other code that figuring if that is correct is asking a lot of an answerer. There are [Rust-specific tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) for reducing your code to a MCVE as well.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for the assessment. I have cut out a lot of details from the post related to avro and I have taken a machete to the play-ground link. It should be a lot more succinct and easy to follow.

Comment: It's *better*, but it's still ~370 lines long. Is it possible to reduce it to deserializing a slice of 3-4 bytes, just those that represent the enum (and data, I suppose)? Then you can remove all of the map-related code. Replacing the custom error with `Box<Error>`, etc. would also reduce a lot of the code. Creating an example that doesn't need to do the bit-twiddling will also make the problem more accessible (and any answer more understandable).

Comment: Also, [someone has already implemented Avro support for Serde](https://github.com/flavray/avro-rs).

Comment: Unfortunately for me, the `deserialize_enum` implementation in avro-rs is a TODO. It is not a complete implementation. And the other popular version does enums but not avro unions.

Comment: I agree, changing this to be an example of "how to use numbers to drive enum deserialization" is a great idea.

Comment: I'd suggest something simple like an array of two`u8`. The first is the variant selector (0, 1) the second is the value (an integer or an ASCII character). Something at this level of complexity.